# Is question asking for mathematical formula for converting meter coordinates into pixels on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is a question asking for mathematical formula for converting meter coordinates into pixels on topic for this site?

To clarify even more, if I have a point `A( 30 meters, 56 meters )` in real life, and wish to display it on computer screen, would a question asking for mathematical formula that converts `A` into pixels be on topic?

Comment: I'll leave to others to answer but I suspect not.  I say this because unless you are also dealing with Geographic or Projected Coordinate Systems (which are on-topic here, and much harder to deal with) the units you assign seem irrelevant and point A is just a Cartesian Coordinate that could be expressed as (30,56).

Comment: @PolyGeo: I suspected as much. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like no answers have been offered yet so I will formalize my comment which is that I think it is off-topic (but not by much).

I say this because unless you are also dealing with Geographic or Projected Coordinate Systems (which are on-topic here, and much harder to deal with) the units you assign seem irrelevant and point A is just a Cartesian Coordinate that could be expressed as (30,56).

Comment: OK, I understand. Thank you. Best regards.